# How to show contents of a card on a separate page [Angular]

Tags: angular, single-page-application, mean-stack

I'm new to Angular. I may not be able to frame the question correctly. But please let me explain. I've created a `MEAN` application. Its is deployed on `heroku`. Here is the [link](http://fierce-woodland-04705.herokuapp.com/articles). If you click on any card i.e `Read more` button, you'll auto scroll to a `div` where contents are displayed. But I want this content to be displayed on a separate fresh page because I'm planning to associate other features such as `Like`, `Upvote`, `Report` etc. Please show me some direction.

PS: [Here](https://github.com/tmtanzeel/social-coder) is the github repo. I've kept it open for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you have `ngFor` to display your articles in your angular `articles-list.component.html` like this

```html
<div class="article" *ngFor="let card of cards" (click)="goToArticle(card )">
  // your card html here
</div>
```

Now you have 2 options.

**Option-1**

One is to make a `service` in set clicked article object in service variable and then get that `article object` on your another page like this in your `data.service.ts`

```
clickedArticle : Object = {}; 

setCLickedArticleObj(obj){
   clickedArticle  = obj;
}

getClickedArticle(){
   return clickedArticle;  
}
```

And in your `ariticles-list.component.ts`

Make a function like this

```
goToArticle(article){
  this._dataService.setCLickedArticleObj(article)
  this.router.navigate('/article-details')
}
```

On your new `page/component` you can get that clicked article object like this

```
// service import 
import {DataService} from 'your-path-to-service'
constructor(private _dataService : DataService){
}
incomingArticleObject : Object = {};
ngOnInit(){
   this.incomingArticleObject  = this._dataService.getClickedArticle()
}
```

**Option-2**

in option 2 i am assuming that you are receiving each article `_id` form the `back-end` api so you can set your clicked article's `_id` to `localstorage` and on your new `page/component` you can get that clicked article details on new component load by hitting `article detail` api.
For this solution you can make a function in your service like this

```
setClickedArticle(id){
   localStorage.setItem('__ai', id)
}

getClickedAritcleId(){
   return localStorage.getItem('__ai');  
}
```

Then in your `articles-list.component.html` you will have like this

```
 <div class="article" *ngFor="let card of cards">
  // your card html here
</div>
```

In your `articles-list.component.ts` you will have a function like this

```
articledId : String = '';

goToArticleDetails(id){
   this._dataService.setClickedArticle(id);
   this.router.navigate('/article-details');
}
```

And on your new `page/component` `article-details.compnent.ts` you can get that article detail on `ngOnInit` like this

```
articleId : String = '';
articleDetails : Object = {};
ngOnInit(){
   this.articleId  = this._dataService.getClickedAritcleId()
   this._dataService.getArticleById(this.articleId).subscribe(article=>{
         this.articleDetails  = article;
   })
}
```

Comment: Sir can you please review my code. I'm facing some problem.

Comment: yes i can but you accepted an answer so it means that you got your solution? Isn't it?

Comment: No, I accepted this answer just now. I implemented this solution. It is working but still there are some warnings on console. Here is the repo: https://github.com/tmtanzeel/social-coder

Comment: Sir I've created a fresh project with minimal code. Please check this https://github.com/tmtanzeel/card-route

Comment: i am saying that just run the project which your created and when you will get warnings in the console so take a screenehot of that and include that screenshot in your question so that i can see them. I don't to clone the whole project and debug myself. Because it's time consuming.

Comment: Sir your solution worked so perfectly. But I want to ask if this the preferred way? Because almost every other answer on the internet suggests `params` and using a separate route For eg `options/:id`. I'm asking this because I don't know. Plz clear my doubts.

Comment: @Tanzeel in angular you have all 3 options. And none of the solution is bad practice. It's totally depend on your comfort that in which method you feel handy and comfortable. I prefer to go with my method-02 as you know in my method-02 _id is setting in `localStorage` so even if user will refresh the page so again `_id` will get from the `localStorage`. I usually to do method-02 in my applications because it ensures security by not using id in url. Because if you will use `_id` in route params so in this way any one can know your route scheme and can try those routes for attacks.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know exactly which part is missing but:

- if you need the navigation bit to the different page:
  [link](https://angular.io/guide/router)
- if you dont know how to bring the data to the different page:[link](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection)

Comment: I am sorry. I need both. But first I would like to solve `routing` part.

Comment: I would recommend to go thru the documentation what I linked, I think its more useful than trying to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is similiar working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vgy6sh?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist%2Flist.component.html)

You can use Router to do the same.

```
 RouterModule.forRoot([
  {path:'',redirectTo: 'list', pathMatch:'full'},
  {path:'list', component:ListComponent},
  {path: 'home/:id', component:HomeComponent}
  ])
],
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted sir. Thanks a ton Sir. :-)