# Rendering card content on a separate route [Angular]

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am learning `MEAN` stack. I've deployed my application [here](https://fierce-woodland-04705.herokuapp.com/articles). Right now If you click on any card i.e. `Read more` button, it will automatically take you to a division where contenets are displayed. But I want to show all that content on a separate route or page because now I am planning to provide some more useful options such as `Like`, `Report`, `Upvote,`Donwvote`, etc. So I made some changes. Please look at them.

**articles.component.html**

```
<div class="row mt-5">
  <div class="col-md-4 mb-3" *ngFor="let article of articles; let i = index;">
    <div class="card text-center">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{article.title}}</h5>
        <a (click)="onPress(i)" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer text-muted">
        {{article.date}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**articles.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ArticlesService } from '../articles.service'; <---- SERVICE FOR READING FROM MONGODB
import {Router, ActivatedRoute }from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  ...
})
export class ArticlesComponent implements OnInit {
  articles=[]
  constructor(private _articleService: ArticlesService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._articleService.getAllArticles()
    .subscribe(
      res => this.articles = res,
      err => console.log(err)
    )
  }

  onPress(id) {
    console.log(id); <--- THIS PRINTS INDEX NO OF THE CARD
    this.router.navigate(['/options',id]);
  }
}
```

And all the options I mentioned above I've kept them in a separate component.

**options-panel.component.html**

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width:50vw">
  <p> {{data }} </p>
  <button (click)="back()"> Back</button>
  <div style="display:flex; margin-top:1rem;padding:1rem;">
    <button style="margin:0.5rem;"> upVote </button>
    <button style="margin:0.5rem;"> DownVote </button>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

**options-panel.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute,Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class OptionsPanelComponent implements OnInit {
  private data;

  constructor(private router: Router,private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(id =>{
    this.data = id.get('id');
    })
  }

  back(){
    this.router.navigate(['../'])
  }
}
```

And please review my **app-routing.module.ts**

```
...
import { ArticlesComponent } from './articles/articles.component';
import { OptionsPanelComponent } from './options-panel/options-panel.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'articles', component: ArticlesComponent},
  {path:'',redirectTo: 'articles', pathMatch:'full'},
  {path: 'options/:id', component:OptionsPanelComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

PS: I read [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router) and [dependancy injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) in Angular. I also tried this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vgy6sh?file=src%2Fapp%2Flist%2Flist.component.html) project.

But I'm getting no errors but blank page.

[image]

Please tell me what else I should do now.

Comment: If you want to display them in a particular location then you should use <router-outlet></router-outlet>. I cant see that anywhere in your code. Are you using router-outlet ?

Comment: Yes @Kazi. I am using it in **app.component.html**. I've added it to **app.moudule.ts** also.

Answer (score 1):

What you showed in your picture was working, but you are printing just the id. You must get the article with that id from somewhere, like you service.

There is some information missing about your project, but you could make something like this.

1. Get the id from the route.
2. Retrieve your article from your service.
3. Show it on front using async if possible.

options-panel.component.ts

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class OptionsPanelComponent implements OnInit {
  private id: number;
  private article$: Observable<Article>;

  constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private _articleService: ArticlesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = Number(this.activateRoute.snapshot.params['id']);
    if (this.id) {
      this.article$ = this._articleService.getArticle(this.id);
    }
  }

  back(){
    this.router.navigate(['../'])
  }
}
```

options-panel.component.html

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width:50vw" *ngIf="article$ | async as article">
  <p> {{ article.content }} </p>
  <button (click)="back()"> Back</button>
  <div style="display:flex; margin-top:1rem;padding:1rem;">
    <button style="margin:0.5rem;"> upVote </button>
    <button style="margin:0.5rem;"> DownVote </button>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

If you are seeing that `Welcome to my app!` and logo, it must be on the `index.html` file.

Comment: Yes Sir. I tried `this.data = id.get(id.content);` also in my **options-panel.component.ts** but VS code is giving red underline.

Comment: No sir. It's still not working. Here is the repo. You can see the entire project. https://github.com/tmtanzeel/social-coder

Comment: @Tanzeel you cannot do ``id.get(id.content)``. Look what I wrote, it should be something like ``this.article$ = this._articleService.fetchArticle(this.id);``

Comment: I already tried this. But `id.content` is red underlined by VS code which means there's a problem, i guess so.

Comment: I have no ``id.content`` on my code, also I wrote ``article.content`` as a guide, beacasue you are using typescript but you are not typing anything. You should set the type of object your functions returns, so everyone could know the properties of your objects like ``article.title``, i don't know if you have an ``article.content`` so I guessed it, please type your vars and methods.

Comment: @Gonzolo.  Sir I don,t want to give up. I tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58836164/how-to-show-contents-of-a-card-on-a-separate-page-angular/58836796?noredirect=1#comment104036499_58836796 also. I created a fresh project with minimal code. Please download it from github: https://github.com/tmtanzeel/card-route.

Comment: I implemented your answer but the page is blank, absolutely blank. And surprisingly there are no errors or warnings on console also.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong then, you want to create a separate link for each `read more`. In that case, you have to add router-link in your html and you have to update your routes as well. Try this one:
Your html:

```
<div class="row mt-5">
  <div class="col-md-4 mb-3" *ngFor="let article of articles; let i = index;">
    <div class="card text-center">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{article.title}}</h5>
        <a [routerLink]="['/'+article.id]" routerLinkActive="router-link-active" (click)="onPress(i)" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer text-muted">
        {{article.date}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this html will generate links for each read more. you also have to update your router and have to put your router-outlet in your desired position.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'articles', component: ArticlesComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'id',
        component: 'Read more component'
      }
    ]
  },

  { path: '', redirectTo: 'articles', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'options/:id', component: OptionsPanelComponent }
];
```

Comment: Thanks Kazi. I'll surely try this solution. You can see the entire project in the meanwhile https://github.com/tmtanzeel/social-coder

Comment: Nope. Getting CORS error. `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/api/articles. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).`